# Как вывести цикличность данных по очередности?

Tags: javascript

```js
let length = 10; // меняется
let range = 2; // тоже меняется
for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
  // нужно вывести цикличность по "range" очередности 
  console.log('Да');
  console.log('Нет');
}
```

На выводе должно быть что то типа этого:

```
Да
Да
Нет
Нет
Да
Да
Нет
Нет
Да
Да
```

Надеюсь правильно поставил вопрос, если что поправьте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    let length = 10; // меняется
    let range = 2; // тоже меняется
    let isYes = false;
    for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
      if (i%range === 0) isYes = !isYes;
      console.log( isYes ? 'Да': 'Нет');
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, как раз то что нужно было